# Is there a way to get the accuracy metric value from deployed model in DataRobot using api code

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, datarobot

Through python Api's , I have uploaded and deployed an ML based custom model on DataRobot Platform successfully.
Now how to get the accuracy metric for the deployed model.

**NOTE:** ACCURACY_METRIC used is 'LOGGLOSS'.

I tried accuracy_over_time.metric. it gave "LogLoss" as an output result.
but how to get the metric value for this LogLoss metric.

I tried accuracy_over_time.metric_values. It says "*there is no attribute as 'metric_values'*."

Comment: some documentation here that might help: https://datarobot-public-api-client.readthedocs-hosted.com/en/v2.28.0/reference/mlops/deployment.html?highlight=accuracy_over_time#accuracy

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for `get_accuracy()`:

```
accuracy = deployment.get_accuracy(
    start_time=datetime(2019, 8, 1, hour=15),
    end_time=datetime(2019, 8, 1, 15, 0)
)
```

You'll need to define the time span if you want accuracy over time, like so:

```
rmse = deployment.get_accuracy_over_time(
    start_time=datetime(2019, 8, 1),
    end_time=datetime(2019, 8, 3),
    bucket_size=construct_duration_string(days=1),
    metric=ACCURACY_METRIC.RMSE
)
```